# How to write regular expression in PHP to find prices / dollar values?

Tags: php, regex

What's the PHP regular expression if I want to find all prices on a page?

So my page has something like:

```
2006 Ford F-250 Lariat - $20995

2005 BMW X3 3.0i***Silver SUV A Must SEE!#($(******* - $18950

2009 Chevrolet Impala LT - $15688
```

How can I write a regular expression to search for $ + any number of numbers after it?

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_match_all("#- (\$\d+)#",$txt,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

to match decimals:

```
preg_match_all("#- (\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)#",$txt,$matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at this:

```
$regex = "@(\$[\.0-9]+)@";
```

Comment: That will match $.4545 and $.4545.45 but not what he wants :/ Plus, no need for a \ between []

Comment: @Pioul: Thanks for pointing it out! Yep your answer is better :D

Comment: I was not trying to compare our answers, just to help you out :)

Comment: Nope. I didn't have any hint of comparing answers or competing. Just wanted the OP to know that yours is better.

Comment: We're on the same page then, great :D

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

This will match $4545 and $4545.45

Comment: This will also match `$4545.4545454545` and not `$4,545.45` :P

Comment: `\$[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` THAT is the mother of all number regexs :DDD

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/(\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)/', $page, $matches);
```

This will work for `$999` and `$999.99` formats, with or without separators.

Comment: Will also work for $4545,.45 :D I love regexs, it puts your brain in such a mess :')

Comment: Will NOT work for $454,454.4 :-* I think we're going too far away from what he wants anyway x)

Comment: But matching one or two decimals is something that could be discussed.. so yeah i'm gonna leave this endless debate and lay down for the night :p

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct regex to match a number starting with a `$` with or without fraction, with or without separators. After the number a whitespace or the end of the line is required.

```
\$(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*+|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?=\s|$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ulug)

This will match

> $1
>   $1234
>   $1234567
>   $1.25
>   $1234
>   $1234.12
>   $1,123.1
>   $1,123.12
>   $12,123.1
>   $123,123.12
>   $123,123,123.12

But not

> $1,12.12
>   $1.123
>   $1,1234
>   $.12